# move div to another div

Tags: javascript, html

how would I move this newly created DIV 'led-box' to another parent div higher up in the document?  Its child 'led-green' needs to be move with it.

Any ideas?  Thank you.

```js
const org = document.querySelector(".directory_availability")
const newItem =  document.createElement('div');   
newItem.className = "led-box";  
newItem.innerHTML = '<div class=led-green></div>';    
org.parentNode.replaceChild(newItem, org);
```

```html
<div class="directory-item">
    <div class="avatar">
    </div>
    <h3 class="display-name">
    </h3>
    <div class="DetailsWrapper">
      <div class="led-box">
        <div class="led-green"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you say "move to another parent div" do you mean nest the newly created div inside the parent div higher up in the DOM structure?

Comment: Could you share an original HTML and an expected output of HTML?

Comment: Hello, I've added the HTML to the post. I need it to be a child of the class=directory-item not the class=DetailsWrapper

Comment: Where is `.directory_availability`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a newly created `<div>` along with it's nested content inside of a parent container higher up in the DOM structure. You could utilize [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) which adds the node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent element. If you wanted to insert the `<div class="led-box">` element before the first child of the parent container `.directory-item` you could use [`ParentNode.prepend()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) instead.

```js
const org = document.querySelector(".directory-item")
const newItem =  document.createElement('div');
newItem.setAttribute("class", "led-box");
newItem.innerHTML = "newly added parent div";

const newItemChild = document.createElement("div");
newItemChild.setAttribute("class", "led-green");
newItemChild.innerHTML = "newly added child div";

// append the 'led-green' div into 'led-box' container
newItem.appendChild(newItemChild);

// append the newly created div into 'directory_availability'
org.appendChild(newItem);
```

```html
<div class="directory-item">
    <div class="avatar"></div>
    <h3 class="display-name">Some Name</h3>
    <div class="DetailsWrapper"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the updated DOM structure, with the `<div class="led-box">` container now a child of the parent container `.directory-item`.

[image: Updated DOM Structure]

Comment: @BrendanLittle Let me know if this helps you out.

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated